# How to create and fill the column during iteration over datarames in a dictionary

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary

I have a .csv file in the dictionary with some data. What I want to do is to iterate over the specific column (with strings) in the dataframe (which is itself in the dictionry) and based on the condition assign specific number at that row, but in the new column.

```py
import os
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
import pandas as pd

### INPUT DIRECTORY
path="folder"


### READING .csv FILES TO THE "dictionary"
files=[f.split('.')[0] for f in listdir(path) if isfile(join(path, f))]
dictionary={}
for file in files:
    dictionary[file]=pd.read_csv(path+'/'+file+'.csv')

### DROPPING 2ND ROW
results={}
for df in dictionary:
    results[str(df)+'_CONSTANT_VAR'] = dictionary[df]
    results[str(df)+'_CONSTANT_VAR'] = results[str(df)+'_CONSTANT_D_SHALE_VAR'].iloc[1:]



for df in results:
    for i in results[str(df)]['FORMATION']:
        if i=='BAL6':
            results[str(df)]['VAR'][i]=10  ### HERE I WANT TO ADD VALUE TO THE NEW COLUMN
```

Unfortunately the code just puts '10' everywhere, and not only at the row where the condition is satisfied. 
Any idea why this happens? and how to do it the way I want?

---

In addition there is an error popping out:

```py
<input>:27: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
```

---

INPUT DATA:

```
wellName    DEPTH   FORMATION   depth2
well name   1000    bal0.5     123
well name   2000    bal1       124
well name   3000    bal0.6     125
well name   4000    bal2       126
well name   5000    bal0.7     127
well name   6000    bal3       128
well name   7000    bal0.8     129
well name   8000    bal4       130
well name   9000    bal0.9     131
well name   10000   bal5       132
well name   11000   bal0.10    133
well name   12000   bal6       134
well name   13000   bal0.11    135
```

OUTPUT IAM GETTING:

```
wellName    DEPTH   FORMATION   depth2 VAR
well name   1000    bal0.5     123     10
well name   2000    bal1       124     10
well name   3000    bal0.6     125     10
well name   4000    bal2       126     10
well name   5000    bal0.7     127     10
well name   6000    bal3       128     10
well name   7000    bal0.8     129     10
well name   8000    bal4       130     10
well name   9000    bal0.9     131     10
well name   10000   bal5       132     10
well name   11000   bal0.10    133     10
well name   12000   bal6       134     10
well name   13000   bal0.11    135     10
```

OUTPUT I WANT TO HAVE:

```
wellName    DEPTH   FORMATION   depth2 VAR
well name   1000    bal0.5     123     
well name   2000    bal1       124     
well name   3000    bal0.6     125     
well name   4000    bal2       126     
well name   5000    bal0.7     127     
well name   6000    bal3       128     
well name   7000    bal0.8     129     
well name   8000    bal4       130     
well name   9000    bal0.9     131     
well name   10000   bal5       132     
well name   11000   bal0.10    133     
well name   12000   bal6       134     10   ### VALUE ADDED ONLY HERE
well name   13000   bal0.11    135
```

Comment: can you add an example of what your data looks like, the output you're getting and the output you are expecting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your dataframe `df` as shown in INPUT DATA you can use the following the conditionally assign a new column `VAR` or assigne a value in the column `VAR` by

```
df.loc[(df.FORMATION == 'bal6'), 'VAR'] = 10
```

The 'error' message you got is actually a warning that you assign a new value to **a copy** of your dataframe and the dataframe itself won't be changed. This is called *chained indexing* and explained [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy).

Comment: Thank you for the explanation of the error. Here is what I get after modifying the code:                                                                                                              
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 24, in <module>
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'loc'

Comment: I franky speaking don't understand why you need all this dictionary stuff. Just do all the data manipulations on pandas dataframes. When done you can convert them to dictionaries if needed by to_dict(). `str(df)` will change every time you change the df, so you'll get new dictionary keys each time.

Comment: The reason of using dictionary is that I will have hundreds of these datasets

Comment: OK, not sure what you tried but it should be: `for df in results:` and on next line indented `results[df].loc[(results[df].FORMATION == 'bal6'), 'VAR'] = 10`

Comment: That works great, there was a mistake in the csv, thats it didn't run properly first time. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help you. If this solved your issue please consider [accepting the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). This keeps this site useful and helps others to quickly find a solution for similar problems. Thanks.